# How to check if the values of two cells exist in two columns of another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, vlookup

I am trying to make a class attendance system where the student checks in by submitting her name into google forms. The final result will be displayed in Google sheets by marking a check box after each of the present student´s name.

So, In Google Sheets,in cell `B3` of `sheet2`, I would like write a formula that checks the following :
if the text in `B2` of `sheet2` (2019-10-20) matches `column A` of `sheet1` where the text contains additional characters (2019-10-20 04:15:25)
AND if the text in `A3` of `sheet2` (Robin) exists in `column B` among the results that were just matched.
If so - return `TRUE`, else return `FALSE`.

IF(AND... for making several conditions

FIND to find the text `2019-10-20` in a column with additional characters

```
=IF(AND(COUNT(FIND(B$2;Sheet1!A:A));A3;Sheet1!B:B);TRUE;FALSE)
```

This is not working but as far as I get.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested by [ask].

Comment: You beginning of solution is not working because you are working with date format (date format is complicated). I'll try an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New solution :

```
=or(ArrayFormula(
regexmatch(iferror(
FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9;int(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9)=B$2)
);$A3)
))
```

It filter the original list to pick up which names appears on a determined dates. Then it checks if the name exist in the list.

---

Using your formula, here's a way to do it :

```
=IF(
    AND(
        or(ArrayFormula(B$2=int(Sheet1!$A3:$A10))),
        or(ArrayFormula($A3=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$8)))

    ,true,false)
```

Expand to right and to the bottom

---

### Some explanation

First condition : `or(ArrayFormula(B$2=int(Sheet1!$A3:$A10))`

1. **How to match the date even with the additional characters ?**

**`int()` ?** 
The first date format `2019-10-20` is an `int`, you can check with `=value` it returns `43758`.
`2019-10-21 04:15:25` is also an `int` but with several numbers after the comma so `=int()` is the quickest way to have a round value like the first date format.

2. **How to check every cells possible ?**

Arrayformula will test the range and return someting like this :

```
False 
False 
False 
True
False
```

3. **There's a match**

Used `or()`

> the OR function returns true if any of the provided arguments are logically true. [The OR function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you pjrng. However I don´t get it to work with the code you suggested. If the date in sheet2 matches one of the dates in the date-column of sheet1, all boxes on that particular date are checked regardless of the names. So it checks the first condition but not the second condition with matching names.

Comment: do you mind sharing a dummy sheet with sample data with what you did ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RezTRvjHY2fzEMGZNxG_J-c1YLZcPDpcfKv4zhAFkKw/edit?usp=sharing

Please note that Swedish Google sheets uses ";" instead of ",".

Comment: OM=IF
OCH=AND
HELTAL=INT

Comment: Don't worry the formulas display according to browser language. 
Anyway, I used another way to resolve it. If this is ok, you can resolve the question and i'll update my answer with the new formula : `=or(ArrayFormula(regexmatch(iferror(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9;int(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9)=B$2));$A3)))` : It first filter name based on the date, then check if the name exist in the list. Should be good now.

Comment: Beautiful, it works now! Thank you so much pjrng!